# Hide overflow on javafx node?

Tags: layout, javafx, overflow

I am trying to create  a panel inside another panel. The inner one is supposed to be larger than the parrent, but whatever extends beyond the parent's bounds should not be painted. How do i do that?

Note: it is important that the child is larger than the parent, so please note that i can not bind childs dimensions to the parent's ones.

Help!

Comment: Look at [How to restrict visibility of items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920680/how-to-restrict-visibility-of-items) and [Clip an HBox inside a GridPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476063/clip-an-hbox-inside-a-gridpane).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better late than never, you simply have to clip your child node to a Rectangle that will act as a viewport :

```
childPane.setClip(new Rectangle(400, 277));
```